# counting measure finite iff $\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)>0\}$ is finite

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\zeta$ be the counting measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a non negative function and $\phi: \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\rightarrow [0,\infty],A\mapsto \int_A fd\zeta$.

Prove or disprove the following statement:
$\phi$ is a finite measure $\Leftrightarrow$ the set $\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)>0\}$ is finite.
I think this is false, because for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, $\phi(\mathbb N)=\int_\mathbb N fd\zeta< \infty$ but the set $\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)>0\}$ is not finite. Is this correct?

Comment: You are close, but actually $\phi(\mathbb{R}) = \infty$ for your $f$.  Modify $f$ so that $\phi(\mathbb{R}) = \phi(\mathbb{N})$ and you'll be finished

Comment: @BrianMoehring Maybe $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\chi_\mathbb N$. Then I have $\phi(\mathbb R)=\int_\mathbb N \frac{1}{1+x^2}d\zeta=\dots <\infty$